# OpenCV with QT on Ubuntu 14.04 Unexpectedly Finished

Tags: qt, opencv, ubuntu-14.04

I need help regarding OpenCV build configuration on QT package 5.5.1 means QT Creator 3.5.1 on Ubuntu 14.04. I am just trying first the *hello world* configuration and I get this error at build:

> The program has unexpectedly finished.

I have read the solution on the SO, but it doesn't work in my scenario. By the way, I have been following [Rodrigo Berriel's Blog](http://rodrigoberriel.com/2014/11/using-opencv-3-qt-creator-3-2-qt-5-3/) (thanks Rodrigo for such an effort)

My configuration is as follows:

test_qt_cv.pro:::

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = test_qt_cv
TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_highgui

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.
```

mainwindow.cpp:::

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    cv::Mat inputImage = cv::imread("/home/ali/Downloads/opencv-3.0.0/samples/data/fruits.jpg");
    if(!inputImage.empty())
        cv::imshow("Display Image", inputImage);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: miki = i am on the linux ubuntu 14.04...yes the libraries are loaded successfully that's why the QT shows me when #include...the problem is somewhere in the LIBS+= because i had the same problem with Eclipse where I have to remove 'lib' prefix before opecv_core f.e. Couldn't find many people using QT for opencv so poorly documented and inclusion ways changes from version to version.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself actually you have to build with cmake again but strictly WITH QT=OFF. But it needs some steps before that as well. Remove every opencv3 files manually from the Ubuntu 14.04. Uninstall QT creater. Than build with cmake again with qt off and than install qt creator hopefully the problem above mentioned will be solved. Cheers.